# Qt4 undefined reference to `QAbstractVideoSurface::QAbstractVideoSurface(QObject*)' in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

I have seen 2 related questions:

- [undefined reference to `strlwr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618316/undefined-reference-to-strlwr)
- [Undefined reference in Qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226212/undefined-reference-in-qt4)

but none of them solved mine. 
So the error is just what the title said and there are same 76 errors in total:

```
/videowidgetsurface.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to `QAbstractVideoSurface::QAbstractVideoSurface(QObject*)'
```

I use `Qt4.8.6`, `QtCreator3.3.2`, `Ubuntu14.04(i386)`.

The .pro file is like this:

```
QT       += core gui multimediakwidgets widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    videowidgetsurface.cpp \
    videoplayer.cpp \
    videowidget.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    videowidgetsurface.h \
    videoplayer.h \
    videowidget.h
```

I tried

```
QT       += core gui multimedia
```

didn't work and this version of `Qt4` doesn't include `QtMultimedia` module.

This is from an example of Qt official tutorial. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QT += multimedia
```

This works on Qt5.

for Qt4 it should be like that:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = multimedia
```

[See an example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/player-player-pro.html).